# how to open process with root privileges using subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, root, popen

I am opening some subproceses in python script and i need one of them to be with root privileges.

Is there a way to do this without running the whole script with root privileges?

```
p1 = "../p1"
p2 = "../p2"
p_root = "../p_root"

proc_P1 = subprocess.Popen(p1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
proc_P2 = subprocess.Popen(p2, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
proc_ROOT = subprocess.Popen(p_root, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two (*) methods I can think of.

## /etc/sudoers.d

Add that one script, `../p_root` invocation to be a passwordless sudo configuration in the `sudoers.d` directory. This configuration will allow *only* `../p_root` to be invoked with passwordless sudo. It is imperative you lock down the script write permissions. At least remove others' permission to write `chmod o-w ../p_root`. Otherwise, someone can exploit this and run arbitrary code as `root` by editing the file and adding their own content.

Each file in `/etc/sudoers.d` contains rules for `sudo`. You can add your own files in that directory, to sanely manage your system. The files within `/etc/sudoers.d` are read in order (convention is to name them `10-something`, `20-else`, etc). They must be edited with `visudo`.

```sh
visudo /etc/sudoers.d/20-special-proot
```

Example content (full path to executable used is mandatory)

```
youruser    ALL=(ALL)   NOPASSWD:   /usr/bin/bash /full/path/to/p_root
```

> [More details about *sudo*](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers)

## SetUID

The second is setting SetUID. This is a file permission that allows executing a script with its owner's permission. i.e., it means that you own the `../p_root` script to `root` and whoever can execute it (group/others) will always run the script as `root`.

```sh
chown root.yourgroup 
chmod u+s ../p_root
chmod o-w ../p_root
```

Again, the same security implications apply here. Whoever can execute this file (group or others have execution permissions, especially) will run everything inside as `root`. If a low privileged user (e.g. others) have write permissions then they can simply edit the file, add themselves to `root` and change your `PS1` to black on black.

> [More details](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-use-special-permissions-the-setuid-setgid-and-sticky-bits)

## sudo (*)

As advised by lior.i, I'm adding this option, too.
You can prefix `sudo` and `bash` to your script's path as the executed command in order to achieve the same goal.

```py
Popen(['sudo', 'bash', '/path/to/script'])
```

Popen is worth learning and the recommended way to execute subprocesses, especially in the long run. In other words, it can do anything the rest can. One of the reasoning for this, I found, is both flexibility and debugging. Flexibility to completely detach the subprocess from its parent or not. By default, if the parent is killed gracefully (SIGINT/Ctrl+C), the child will be signaled to die, too. Similarly, they're also attached at their `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` file descriptor. Perhaps you want to make use of a new file descriptor for some crafty magic.

A consideration you should take if you use this is not using it in production. Leaving an applicative user with passwordless sudo is a security risk similar to just running everything as root.

Comment: ok, sounds good, but the problem I see with this solutions is that in every machine that I will run it I would need to change the exe file permission  or the /etc/sudoers.d.
isn't there a way that I can run it with root permission from within the python script?
like "os.system('sudo ../p_root')" but with Popen.

Comment: @lior.i Sure, you can prefix `sudo` and `bash` to your script's path. `Popen(['sudo', 'bash', '/path/to/script'])`. Basically, `Popen` is the recommended way to execute subprocesses and none of the other alternatives. In other ways, it can do anything the rest can.

Comment: Perfect,
Thank you @edd

Comment: I think it should be part of the answer @edd

Comment: @lior.i Completely fair. Added to the answer.